# Apache LibCloud and Rackspace Cloudfiles

Tags: python, apache, cloudfiles, libcloud

I've started using the Apache libcloud library with python to allow me to talk to rackspace cloudfiles in python3 (pyrax is 2 only)

I've got this running successfully and am uploading files / creating containers etc happily.

Sadly, I appear to only be able to get the HTTP url for the items uploaded:

```html
driver.get_object_cdn_url(obj)
```

This will return the HTTP url for the object I've just uploaded.

Is there a way to get the OTHER url(s) (HTTPS / Streaming etc) via this library (I can't fathom it from the documentation!)

Answer (score 0):

The driver allows you to first enable CDN functionality on the container.

```
driver.enable_container_cdn(container)
```

There isn't a method to directly get the streaming URL, `get_container_cdn_url` only responds with the static CDN URL. This code snippet would get the information directly from the API:

```
from libcloud.utils.py3 import urlquote
container_name = '<your container name'
response = driver.connection.request('/%s' % (urlquote(container_name)),
                                       method='HEAD',
                                       cdn_request=True)
uri = response.headers['x-cdn-uri']
ssl_uri = response.headers['x-cdn-ssl-uri']
stream_uri = response.headers['x-cdn-streaming-uri']
```

See [these reference docs](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/v1/cdn-api-reference/cdn-container-services-operations/#id3) for details.